# Keycloak java api fetch service account user for given client

Tags: jboss, transactions, keycloak, jta, keycloak-services

I'm using Keycloak version 3.4.3.Final community version (I know it's an older version and cannot update it because of business reasons)  and it's corresponding java client, I have created a client with flag `serviceAccountEnabled` set to `true` and need to assign `realm-management` client's roles to it i.e. from section `service-account-roles`.

I'm able to create client successfully but not able to assign `realm-management` client's roles to it as it requires fetching of `service-account-user` which is returning null everytime, below is my code snippet

Code to create client

```
            KeycloakTransaction tx = session.getTransactionManager();
            tx.begin();
            ClientModel clientModel = myRealm.addClient("myClient-id");
            clientModel.setClientId("myClient-id");
            clientModel.setClientAuthenticatorType("client-secret");
            clientModel.setStandardFlowEnabled(false);
            clientModel.setWebOrigins(Collections.emptySet());
            clientModel.setRedirectUris(Collections.emptySet());
            clientModel.setDirectAccessGrantsEnabled(false);
            clientModel.setImplicitFlowEnabled(false);
            clientModel.setServiceAccountsEnabled(true);
            clientModel.setPublicClient(false);
            clientModel.setProtocol("openid-connect");
            clientModel.setFullScopeAllowed(false);
            //need to inject this from env
            clientModel.setSecret("12345");
            clientModel.updateClient();
            commitOrRollbackTransaction(tx);
```

Code to assign `realm-management` roles to client's `service-account-user`

```
KeycloakTransaction tx = session.getTransactionManager();
tx.begin();
RealmModel myRealm = keycloakSession.realms().getRealmByName("myRealm");
ClientModel clientModel = myRealm.getClientByClientId("myClient-id");
ClientModel realmManagementClient = myRealm.getClientByClientId("realm-management");
Set<RoleModel> roles = realmManagementClient.getRoles();
UserModel serviceAccountUser = keycloakSession.users().getServiceAccount(clientModel);
if(serviceAccountUser != null){
   roles.stream().forEach(r -> serviceAccountUser.grantRole(r));
 }
tx.commit();
```

The issue is, I do not get `service-account-user` for the client I created in previous step, however I've verified that user got created, also I can fetch `service-account-user` for existing clients, it seems more like a transaction issue but I'm performing client creation and roles assignment in two different sessions.

Can someone please point me where I'm mistaking or point me to direction how to fetch `service-account-user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using RealmManager and ClientManager keycloak API.